# RAID 1 mirror disk failure detection

Tags: windows-server-2008, raid, mirror

In the BIOS of an ASUS motherboard I've set up a RAID 1 mirror out of two hard drives. All is working fine at present. I have two OS installed on the machine: Windows Server 2008 R2 and Windows 7.

My question is a general one: 
In case of a failure of one of the two hard drives composing the mirror, will I be somehow notified by the system or should I check it myself constantly? In case I should do it myself then how to do it? By reading logs from time to time or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using onboard RAID and the correct Windows drivers are installed, this most likely will appear as an Error event in the System log. You could test this by making a full backup, disconnecting one of the drives, starting Windows, and checking Event Viewer for evidence of a RAID fault.

Answer (score 0):

you will get a raid management software with asus motherboard that can be configured to send you a regular update via mail. in case of failure too you will be notified in screen. 
i have seen in most of asus motherboard raid management software are reliable and most importantly they work well.